# Store Data Inside an Array with the Checkbox as the Factor?

Tags: php, mysql

Script:

```
<?php

    include("connect.php");

?>
<?php

    /*
     * SELECT THE ROW BY THE "THREAD_ID"
     */

    $tqs = "SELECT * FROM `thread` WHERE `id` = '" . $_GET['thread_id'] . "'";
    $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tqr);

?>
<?php
    /*
     * FETCH HASHTAG NAMES
     * PRINT HASHTAG NAMES INSIDE THE INPUT FIELDS
     */

    // Store the hashtag ID numbers inside an array.
    $explode_hashtags = explode(", ", $row['hashtag_id']);

    // Fetch the hashtag names from the table.
    // And store the hashtag names inside the array "$fetch_array_hashtags".
    $fetch_array_hashtags = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($explode_hashtags); $i++){
        $tqs_hashtags = "SELECT `hashtag` FROM `hashtags` WHERE `id` = '" . $explode_hashtags[$i] . "'";
        $tqr_hashtags = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs_hashtags) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
        $row_hashtags = mysqli_fetch_array($tqr_hashtags);
        $fetch_array_hashtags[] = $row_hashtags['hashtag'];
    }

?>
<?php

    echo "<form method='POST' action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "'>";

    echo "<input type='hidden' name='thread_id' value='" . $_GET['thread_id'] . "' />";

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fetch_array_hashtags); $i++) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='hashtag_modify_checkbox[]' value='" . $explode_hashtags[$i] . "' />";
        echo "Modify";
        echo "<input type='text' name='hashtag[]' value='" . $fetch_array_hashtags[$i] . "' />";
    }

    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' />";
    echo "</form>";

?>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $tqs = "SELECT `hashtag_id` FROM `thread` WHERE `id` = '" . $_POST['thread_id'] . "'";
        $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tqr);

        // Store the hashtag ID numbers inside an array.
        $explode_hashtags = explode(", ", $row['hashtag_id']);

        // Store the hashtag names inside an array.
        $hashtags = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['hashtag']); $i++) {
            if (!empty($_POST['hashtag'][$i])) {
                $hashtags[] = $_POST['hashtag'][$i];
            }
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < count($explode_hashtags); $i++){
            $tqs_hashtags_update = "UPDATE `hashtags` SET `hashtag` = '" . $hashtags[$i] . "' WHERE `id` = '" . $explode_hashtags[$i] . "'";
            //$tqs_hashtags_update = "UPDATE `hashtags` SET `hashtag` = '#blue_topy' WHERE `id` = '116'";
            $tqr_hashtags_update = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs_hashtags_update) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
        }

    }

?>
```

This is intended for the use in an admin panel.

The input fields contain the "hashtags" inside of them, they can be edited and the table can be updated.

**My problem is:** when ***no editing*** has been done to the "hashtags" then the SQL query nevertheless updates ***all*** of the "hashtags" to the table.
Basically, if I only edit ***one*** "hashtag" I would want just that ***one*** "hashtag" to be updated to the table in MySQL and the other "hashtags" not.

I thought of using a checkbox next to the input fields. Where I can check the "modify checkbox" and then edit the "hashtag", and ***then*** ***only*** the "hashtags" with the ***"checkbox checked"*** should get stored inside an array, so with that array the updating to the table can be done.

My question is, how can I store only ***those*** hashtags *(from the input fields)* inside an array, ***where the checkboxes are checked***? So I can use that array to update the table with just ***those*** "hashtags", which ***actually*** have gotten edited.

Comment: From what I can tell, `hashtag_modify_checkbox` isn't defined as a POST variable. You're using just `$explode_hashtags[$i]` in the checkbox's value.

Comment: I'm curious, what happens to your GET['thread_id'] variable (in the hidden input) once you have posted the form. Aren't you going to lose the value? (I know this isn't completely related to your question...just an observation.

Comment: GhostRider, quick elaboration: when the "submit" button has gotten clicked the URL changes from "*.php?thread_id=number" to "*.php", because of that I also use "thread_id" through the POST method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to add hidden values for the old hashtags to check if they have changed. Then just update the changed hashtags.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($fetch_array_hashtags); $i++) {
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='hashtag_old[]' value='".$fetch_array_hashtags[$i]."' />";
    echo "Modify";
    echo "<input type='text' name='hashtag[]' value='".$fetch_array_hashtags[$i]."' />";
}
# ... some more code ...
$hashtags = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['hashtag']); $i++) {
    if (!empty($_POST['hashtag'][$i]) and $_POST['hashtag'][$i]<>$_POST['hashtag_old'][$i]) {
        $hashtags[] = $_POST['hashtag'][$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This suggestion has worked for myself!

Answer (score 0):

Store your check box results in an array with the same order as your hash tags, then add a conditional for the update.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($explode_hashtags); $i++){

        if ($checkArray[$i] === true){
        $tqs_hashtags_update = "UPDATE `hashtags` SET `hashtag` = '" . $hashtags[$i] . "' WHERE `id` = '" . $explode_hashtags[$i] . "'";
        //$tqs_hashtags_update = "UPDATE `hashtags` SET `hashtag` = '#blue_topy' WHERE `id` = '116'";
        $tqr_hashtags_update = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs_hashtags_update) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    }
    }
```

Then it will only update hash tags where the check box has been marked